# Responsiveness not working at certain condition only

Tags: html, css, sass

So I am trying to make my site it's not working properly. Infact only visibility is working but sizes and other stuffs doesn't work. I am still learning stuffs.
[www.ditikrimal.com.np](http://www.ditikrimal.com.np)
Here is my site link and there is image which responses for the visibility:hidden; but doesn't work with width, height.
Same goes for that text section. I can't change that text section's width.
Below is my code,
Html for these elements are here,

```
  <div class="mainContent">
        <img src="BgImg.png" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>
    <div class="textContent">
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum....
        </p>
    </div>

@media (max-width: 768px) {

.mainContent img{
 margin-left:100px;
 }
.textContent{
width: 100px;
font-size: 15px;
}

}
```

I haven't published this code to the site but locally it doesn't work.
I have used  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in my code too. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please also add the html that is relevant here and its default width/margin styling so we can see what it is and what isn't working.

Comment: Your media query is overwritten by the code. You could simply add the media query definition at the end of your code.

Comment: I have added html too please check it out.

Comment: Media query is at end of the code. I don't think it's being over written. Also, Like how can it be overwritten ? by another media query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amaury Hanser said right.

Browser read your CSS line by line, Check below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: let me try this. I didn't think media query will be affected by this. I made previous website but this didn't affect anything. But let me try and see. I will update

Comment: Ohhh I got it. I didn't thought like that. It worked thanks.